# Is kurtosis and skewness subadditive?

Tags: skewness, kurtosis

I would like to ask a question regarding the subadditivity of high-order statistics such as Kurtosis and Skewness. Here Kurtosis refers to actual Kurtosis instead of excess Kurtosis.

Are they sub-additive， i.e. A is denoted as one financial asset's return time series, and B is denoted as that of another asset.  A+B means the portfolio of A and B at any possible combinations. So the question asks whether the (empirical sample) Kurtosis of a portfolio is smaller or equal to the summation of Kurtosis of each individual asset.

```
Kurt (A+B)<=Kurt (A) + Kurt (B)    

Skew (A+B)<=Skew (A) +Skew (B).
```

Is that the case?

Comment: Please explain what kinds of mathematical objects "A" and "B" refer to and what the operation "+" is.  You also need to tell us what you mean by "kurtosis" and "skewness" because there are multiple different formulas and concepts for both (depending on whether you are discussing a moment, a moment estimate, or -- in the case of skewness -- one of the many different definitions of the skewness of a random variable or distribution).

Comment: Although I voted to reopen this post after the edits, it's worth remarking it is still ambiguous, because the answer depends on whether you mean the actual kurtosis or the *excess kurtosis.*  The skewness question is easily resolved by considering the case where both skewnesses are negative.

Comment: Thanks, I have reedited the question to clarify that I meant the actual Kurtosis

Comment: Although a time series can never be exactly the same as a Normal random variable, it can come close.  So, for insight, consider what happens to the kurtosis of a sum of independent Normal variables.

Comment: I'm never clear on whether targeted quantities such as skewness and kurtosis are the best ways to discuss distributional shapes as opposed to quantile-based measures.